# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use problem 12

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

```
CREATE TABLE Meta_data(Name_list_id VARCHAR DEFAULT (CONCAT('NL', AUTO_INCREMENT)),Result_id VARCHAR DEFAULT (CONCAT('RS', AUTO_INCREMENT)),No_of_subject int);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf8h6.png)

---

in above Name_list_id generate NL01,NL02,NL03....,
and Result_id generate RS01,RS02,RS03...,
can help to correct solution provide this query
for "mysql database"

Comment: ' correct solution' - to what I wonder.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if your `ID` values are numbers, not strings. Your syntax is incorrect - you are not allowed to create `AUTO_INCREMENT` on strings. Also, you are not able to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in [`GENERATED`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/) columns.

And now you are looking for the following:

```
NL01,NL02,NL03, ...
```

but what if we have 99+ records?

If you are using numbers, you will be able to format them when the data is read. For example, using [LPAD](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lpad-function.php) function:

```
SELECT CONCAT('NL',LPAD(result_id,5,'0'))
FROM mytable
```